# Can't change read only folder in windows 7

Tags: windows

I'm trying to run a Spring MVC 2.5 tutorial and when I run the ant script for a deploy, I get this error: 
deploy:
     [copy] Copying 2 files to C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.8\webapps\c:\projects\workspace\springapp

BUILD FAILED
C:\projects\workspace\springapp\build.xml:46: Failed to copy C:\projects\workspace\springapp\war\WEB-INF\web.xml to C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.8\webapps\c:\projects\workspace\springapp\WEB-INF\web.xml due to failed to create the parent directory for C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.8\webapps\c:\projects\workspace\springapp\WEB-INF\web.xml

After reviewing the directory: springapp I saw the properties as read-only.  No problem I thought as I'm logging in as administrator.  However, changing the uac settings, going to a command prompt as admin and then trying to change the properties of the folder with attrib, making me the owner of the folder, changing the security settings etc... did nothing.  I can't seem to change this folder to anything.

So my question is, how do I change the settings on that folder so ANT can make changes to that folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Moab's answer would have worked normally, but my root problem was a corrupted user profile.  So I went and followed the steps from the Microsoft website [link](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/fix-a-corrupted-user-profile) and it solved the problem.

I hope this helps someone if they run into this same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Open an elevated command prompt

a. Type the following command and press Enter key:

> takeown /f [path to folder] /r /d y

b. To assign the Administrators group Full Control Permissions for the folder, use this command and hit Enter key:

> icacls [path to folder] /grant administrators:F /T

The /T parameter is added so that the operation is carried out through all the sub-directories and files within that folder.

Comment: The first command worked, but I'm getting icacis is not recognized as an internal or external command error.

Comment: icac_L_s, not icac_I_s.

Comment: Okay, the command ran but still didn't work. I may have a corrupted user profile.